# Module inclusion: not intended for consumption by other components - gradle:3.0.0-alpha2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, android-studio-3.0

Upgraded to:

- Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2
- com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2

I have a multi-module project (main app + sub modules)

Inclusion inside the main app:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':testlib', configuration: 'default')
}
```

The testlib is defined as a simple android library project and works normally when included with gradle 2.3.0 and via compile project(path: ':testlib')

**I get the following gradle error message:**

*Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:devDebug_signedCompileClasspath'.
Selected configuration 'default' on 'project :testlib' 
    but it can't be used as a project dependency because 
    it isn't intended for consumption by other components.*

What does "*isn't intended for consumption by other components*" mean in this context? The module is defined as an android library.

Here is the build.gradle of the testlib:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: In your root `build.gradle`, do you add ` maven {
          url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }` ?

Comment: @cole It did not make a difference. The error message is still the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also got this error.  Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4 just came out.  I updated to it, which also updates gradle to 4.0rc1.

The problem went away on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

alter your **Top-level build file** (aka root gradle)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
```

still not working?

update dist-url (inside gradle-wrapper.properties)

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-rc-1-all.zip
```